# Why won't fstab remount my Samba drives at boot?

Tags: mount, fstab

I have a couple of lines in my /etc/fstab file:

```
//qnas01/mediaA /media/A cifs credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000,sec=ntlm 0 0
//qnas01/mediaB /media/B cifs credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

But after each new boot they aren't connected. I can go to a terminal and type:

```
sudo mount -a
```

and presto, they're there. Why doesn't it mount them when I boot?

The .smbcredentials file belongs to `root` user with `rw` access.

Comment: What distribution and what init system are you using? How is your network configured? One possible explanation is that the boot-time mounting is attempted before the network is accessible.

Comment: Have you tried adding `_netdev` to the mount options in case it's trying to mount before networking is up?